# Database Resources setup in local.xml + magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, master-slave

I want to setup default_setup and default_read as different databases for both in Magento 1.9. Now the thing is there is something wrong with default_setup DB but default_read DB is proper so homepage should work properly by default_read database right? Or is it required default_setup database to run front-end compulsory?